# Nuxt.js default layout not being applied

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm brand new to using Nuxt.js, and having an issue: When I created my project, the layouts folder wasn't generated automatically as documented. I added it manually, but default.vue is not being applied anywhere. Here is `layouts/default.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <AppHeader/>
      <Nuxt/>
  </div>
</template>
```

I've tried things such as manually setting `default` as the layout in pages and manually importing the `AppHeader` component in `default.vue` (although this is definitely not the issue as other HTML I put there doesn't get rendered either). Not sure what's going wrong here, scratching my head. Using `nuxt 2.15.7`. If there's any additional detail needed please let me know what and I'll gladly provide, thanks.

Comment: Hm, this should work properly. Creating a new `layouts` directory is fine and you did well. Do you have a Github repo link?

Comment: Have You created the project from CLI or manually?  by default it should use the file in directory layouts/default as You pointed above. Have the console pointed any error?

So You have tried this:
Create another file ex. blog.vue in layouts directory and just pust there the same syntax:

<template>
  <div>
      <AppHeader/>
      <Nuxt/>
  </div>
</template>
--- and then in any of Your page
<script>
export default {
  layout: 'blog',
}
</script>



Or let create another project by command:
npm init nuxt-app nuxt-test-app and just run it and see if it works.

Comment: I am facing same issue created nuxt priject with yarn and not working
it is weird but after a server restart it started working again 

Answer (score 31):

Today, I faced the same issue, I just stop the dev command and did `"npm run dev"` again.

It woked like a charm.

Comment: in my case `yarn dev`, but it worked like a charm. thanks

Comment: It's working, i use `yarn dev`. My code works perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't really fix the problem as it comes back all the time. I haven't figured out what causes it though ...

Answer (score 11):

Was Facing this same issue, it was fixed by wrapping contents of app.vue with `<NuxtLayout></NuxtLayout>`

example:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

For more details look here:
https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/2883

Answer (score 8):

I also faced this issue today, and it took my like 15 minutes to realize...

I just named my folder `layout` instead of `layouts` :')

I'm posting it just in case someone else is as distracted as I am

Comment: in my case it's because my default layout name was `Default.vue` instead of `default.vue`, also commenting just in case someone made this silly mistake

Comment: you have to restart the development server as well -- saying this in case you might think why the solution does not work. lol

Answer (score 0):

Change some packages version

```json
"core-js": "^3.19.3",
"nuxt": "^2.15.8",
"vue": "^2.6.14",
"vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
"webpack": "^4.46.0"
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I solved it:

```html
<template>
  <NuxtLayout :name="layout">
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<script setup>
// You might choose this based on an API call or logged-in status
const layout = "custom";
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just define your components folder path in `nuxt.config.js`

eg:

```
components: {
    dirs: [
      '~/shared',
      '~/shared/atoms',
      '~/shared/molecules',
      '~/shared/organisams',
    ]
  },
```